# No se reconocen dependencias, Kali linux

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, kali-linux

Buen dia, Tengo un problema con las dependencias de mi so, Tengo instalado kali linux en VirtualBox, El problema esta en que algunas herramientas no me reconocen dependencias que las tengo instaladas, Me dan como respuesta que No esta instalada. Eh intentado upgrade,update, de todo pero me sigue dando el mismo problema. Alguna solucion?

Comment: Hola. Creo que el lugar más adecuado para tu pregunta es el foro [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=kali). Por el formato de [es.so] tratamos en general problemas de programación y muy pocas veces se aborda el problema de configuración de sistemas operativos. Te sugiero que des una mirada a está respuesta a una pregunta similar a la tuya: [If you need to ask, then Kali Linux is not the right distribution for you.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/426451). Por favor no lo tomes a mal. Sólo piensa que debes ser **muy fuerte** en linux antes de lidiar con Kali.

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta estos comandos por orden y espero que se te solucione, si no comentame :P

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: también lo he hecho y el mismo resultado :( , Alguna recomendación mas?

Comment: edita tu publicacion y si puedes aporta los errores que te devuelve por terminal (referente a que no reconozcan las dependencias) :S